# Nodejs waiting for Localhost..... and fetching data

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I don't know particularly if this is a react-router issue im having or a nested route issue, or even a data issue. I'm hacking together a isomorphic single page app with react flux and node/express and i'm having trouble understanding why sometimes on my /reports and /reports/:id routes it will spit out no data/or empty array if I cycle through a lot of routes (like moving back and forth between /reports and every different /reports/:id eventually one of them will spit undefined (any random one at that moment) and when I return to my dashboard and then to my data (/reports) its all empty. If I hit refresh, it will say waiting for localhost... forever (like 1 min+ which is forever on the web) and then i'd have to restart the server.

My routes are this :

```
<Route>
 <Route name ="dash" path="/dashboard" handler={App}>
    <Route name ="dashboard" path="/dashboard" handler={Dashboard}/>


    <Route name ="assignReport" path="/user" handler={AssignReport}/>
    <Route name ="assignReported" path="/user/:id" handler={AssignReported}/>
    <Route name ="employees" path="/employees" handler={Employees}/>
    <Route name ="reports" path="/reports" handler={Report}/>
      <Route name ="singlereports" path="/reports/:id" handler={ReportView}/>
      <Route name ="addsubreport" path="/reports/:id/addsubreport" handler={AddSubreport}/>
      <Route name ="editreports" path="/reports/:id/edit" handler={EditReport}/>
      <Route name ="MyEmployees" path="/MEmployees" handler={MyEmployees}/>
      <Route name ="AllEmployees" path="/AEmployees" handler={AllEmployees}/>
      <Route name ="Profile" path="/profile" handler={Profile}/>
      <Route name ="reportstocomplete" path="/reportsc" handler={ReportsToComplete}/>
    <Route name ="addReport" path="/addReport" handler={AddReports}/>
    <Route name ="readme" path="/readme" handler={Readme}/>
    <Route name ="statistics" path="/statistics" handler={Stats}/>
    <Route name ="signup" path="/signup" handler={Signup} />
    <Route name ="login" path="/" handler={Login} />
    <Route name ="newreport" path="/newreport" handler={NewReport}/>
    <Route name ="templatereport" path="/templatereport" handler={TemplateReport}/>
 </Route>
</Route>
```

EDIT: I realize that it is probably not a routing issue but most likely a ajax issue. I might be loading asynchronous data too slow. I grab every document by searching by user name rather than id which might be the case. Any thoughts?

EDIT: It might not even be a ajax issue, the problem doesn't occur on IE, i can refresh and GET the data over and over again however it has trouble POST' ing data on IE. On chrome it will say waiting for localhost... for a while.

EDIT: I am able to spam the routes on firefox, and continously it will always work fine. It does not work fine when I type in localhost:3000 in the browser, therefore typing in the IP allows for it to work (127.0.0.1); Doing the same for chrome, I still get undefined and stuck on localhost after a bunch of spams (10 - 20 route spams(clicking back and forward/ alt right and alt left)

Answer (score 1):

If you use nested routing you should use the route as a parent. like

```
<Route name=parent handler={Report}>
  <Route name=child handler={ReportChild}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: Still doesnt stop the issue

Comment: im looking into your route and found something off the mark. you are not including the index handler. which is `<Route path="/" handler={Index}>` before all of your other routes, then inside that Index component you put your `<RouteHandler/>` it would mean that all of your components will be rendered inside Index depending on what route path you are in. if you want login to be the default. add `<DefaultRoute name="login" handler={Login}/>` hope helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. I'm confused as to why the server gets so busy when doing so.